# Show gerrit users in the apache log

Tags: apache, proxy, gerrit

I'm using apache as a reverse proxy for gerrit, but I want to display gerrit's user information in the apache log. What should I do?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7wl7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Google BBS, but it only started to show up in gerrit version 2.15, and I'm **'lucky'** to be using version 2.14.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/PYlPmVrSiXk

Comment: O, hi again. 1) 2.14.x is already EOL, 2.15.x will soon be. Please upgrade. 2) This site (Stack Overflow) is the wrong place to ask server configuration question. I think ServerFault is a better place for that. 3) To also link my answer from the Gerrit mailing list here: https://serverfault.com/a/728403/135437